# Touches Moved on uibutton is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, touchesmoved

I have a view which is completely covered with `UIButtons`. I want to implement touches moved and based on the location of the finger I want to identify the button behind it and perform desired action. The problem I am facing is touches moved method is never called.

Comment: It is becasue your touches are intercepted by all those buttons. You should either cover those buttons with uiview or use uiview instead of buttons and add action based on touch!

Comment: I cannot add uiview on top of button because i have ibactiob methods on those buttons. I am trying this to implrmrnt swipe keyboard.

Comment: Uibutton is itself a uiview first so, you can remove those buttons and put uivies in their place or you can disable the uibutton by setting  userInteraction NO.

Comment: If i make userinteraction to NO, touch up inside - IBAction will not work right.

Comment: Yes, but you can call it manually once you finalise the view where the touch is ended!

Comment: Swipes are working. But is there a way to differentiate swipes and tap. Like swipe to this action and for tap do this.

Comment: I got everything working now.